# Install Gnome-Manual-Duplex in 20.04

Tags: 20.04, duplex-printing

Until I upgraded to 20.04 I used Gnome-Manual-Duplex to print front to back on my HP laserjet.

However this package depends on `python-gamin` and `python-cups` which are no longer available in the repos.

How do I re-install Gnome-Manual-Duplex and its dependencies in Focal Fossa?

Comment: `python-gamin` relied on `python2` which is EOL & thus not supported in focal. https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/python-gamin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still can download and install it by using dependencies from 19.10:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/python-cups/python-cups_1.9.73-2build2_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install -y ./python-cups_1.9.73-2build2_amd64.deb

wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gamin/python-gamin_0.1.10-5build1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install -y ./python-gamin_0.1.10-5build1_amd64.deb

wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-gtk2_2.24.0-6_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install -y ./python-gtk2_2.24.0-6_amd64.deb

wget https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/g-manual-duplex/gnome-manual-duplex_0.70_all.deb
sudo apt-get install -y ./gnome-manual-duplex_0.70_all.deb
```

and use it as before.

Comment: I'm hesitant to install packages from an older version of Ubuntu, lest it might conflict or break things.

Comment: Then I do not understand your problem. This solution will work, I have checked it on VM. So it is a solution. These packages maybe a leftover of 19.10 system which maybe upgraded to 20.04 LTS. The APT on 20.04 LTS will mark them as locally installed, there is no risk here.

Comment: OK. I'm trusting this won't cause problems, while hoping GMD gets ported to python3.